# Is it possible to migrate from Cassandra Community edition to Datastax Enterprise edition

Tags: datastax-enterprise

We currently have a 4 node cluster running Cassandra 2.0 community edition and would like to know if we can migrate to Datastax enterprise edition. Is there any documentation available for this.

Answer (score 4):

Check the DataStax Upgrade Guide:

"Upgrading from Datastax Community to DataStax Enterprise"
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdAnyVersion.html